# powershell execute oracle query and export csv

Tags: oracle, powershell, export-to-csv, executequery

I am new to powershell. I have to execute a query in Oracle database and export the result to CSV and then put that in an FTP location. I've tried various options and its not working.

Please let me know how to export the result to CSV.

Comment: You should edit your question to include the code you've tried and explain how it fails/doesn't work the way you intended.

Comment: Simply use `SPOOL`. It dumps the query result to the file of your choice.

Comment: what options have you tried, and what exactly is not working?